# Add a feature to see the most famous user

Tags: feature-request

Say based:

- profile views

It will be cool to give votes/ and down votes for a creative profile description.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2785/what-makes-a-sopedians-profile-worth-visiting-data-dump-analysis

Comment: I would say Alan Kay is probably the most famous user, for certain levels of "use".

Comment: This feels more than a little tautological.

Answer (score 6):

> It will be cool to give votes/ and
>   down votes for a creative profile
>   description.

No it wouldn't.  It would be pretty much the antithesis of how SO is supposed to work.  Questions and answers are supposed to be judged upon their own merit, which earns their author reputation.  A user is not supposed to get rep because his profile is little more than -- hypothetically -- a profanity-laden, drunken tirade about lasers.

Comment: Are you afraid of linking to it?

Comment: I'd upvote it just based on the lasers part :)

Answer (score 3):

We already have the **Users** page. There's no need for more. Besides, we all know who Jon Skeet is :)

Comment: Obligatory comment: Who is this Jon Skeet?

Comment: I have no idea, but I keep reading about him on meta :)